# Gramblr conflict with firewall (500 - internal server error)

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall

I'm using windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit) and I set its firewall to block all inbound and outbound connections so I can choose which app will access to network by creating those rules in my firewall.
I have no problem with other apps except Gramblr! I have defined the rule in firewall for gramblr.exe but still getting this error :

> 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> Internal Server Error
>
> Internal error information: Permission denied.

It wants to conncet to this address "http://localhost.gramblr.com:4343/", I even used chrome but still got the same error!
Please tell me which file should I put in my Firewall rules to make it work.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too and found that it was because
I ran Gramblr straight from the downloaded .zip file, rather than extracting first before running!
So - try:

- uninstalling Gramblr
- revisiting the install file
- extract Gramblr
- and then run.
  This fixed the problem for me.